# Google OAuth 2.0. javascript API doesn't stay "logged in" after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus

I'm developing an AngularJS application with google+ user authentication. I've taken the package angular-google-plus (an Angular module which handles the login with the Google+ API).

At it's heart, the login will use the gapi object:

`gapi.auth.authorize(...)`

Everything is working while the page doesn't refresh. For example, I can get the current user from the API with: 
`gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function() { ... })` but again, the state wont be kept when I refresh the page.

What do I need to do in order to maintain the "Logged-In" state after the page is refreshed ? it seems the google api "forgets" the state.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? Would it be an idea to store the token in localStorage then match against the one assigned from google. If all matches, stay logged in, otherwise refresh the token.

Comment: @DanWhiteside You cannot make it stay logged in by storing or refreshing the token. Maybe you can do something else to re-login with the token.

Answer (score 1):

I feel unfamiliar with your code... Is it really `OAuth 2.0`?
I think you are talking about [Google Sign-In JavaScript client](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) because you are mentioning page refresh.

I believe that you cannot immediately get any information like `gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo` because there is no code to wait for an instance to be initialized.

Do something like the following with `then`:

```
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "...", ...}).then(function(googleAuth) { // onInit
  console.log(googleAuth.isSignedIn.get());
}, function() { // onError
});
```